# What is chakshumati vidya for healthy eyes?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, ayurveda, manuscripts, krishna-yajurveda

I have heard that chakshumati vidya is good for curing eye problems and eye sight. I wish to know what is the origin of it and the details and procedure of chakshumati vidya, along with the stotra.

Comment: If I am correct then it refers to [Chakshupanoisht](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-108UpanishadsPart-3SadhanaKhand/page/n53/mode/2up) , this is the sanskrit [doc](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/chakshu.html) someone can look them up to answer.

Comment: If anyone is trying this vidya, my personal opinion is that, it really works. I have got a small issue with my eye and nothing helped. Then I did this vidya for 11 days. There is good improvement. I have read that this vidya needs to be done for 3 months for bigger problems. Please try it 

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the minor Upanishads namely **चाक्षुषोपनिषद् cākṣuṣopaniṣad.** The knowledge gained from this Upanishad is capable of completely destroying the diseases of the eyes. This makes the eyes sparkle. Ahirbudhnya is the seer of the mantras of this visual knowledge. Chhand is Gayatri and the deity Surya (Savita) is the Lord. It is used for the prevention of eye diseases. It is as follows:

```
ॐ अथातश्चाक्षुषीं पठितसिद्धविद्यां चक्षुरोगहरां व्याख्यास्यामः ।
यच्चक्षूरोगाः सर्वतो नश्यंति ।
चाक्षुषी दीप्तिर्भविष्यतीति । तस्याश्चाक्षुषीविद्याया अहिर्बुध्न्य ऋषिः । गायत्री छन्दः ।
सूर्यो देवता ।
चक्षुरोगनिवृत्तये जपे विनियोगः।
ॐ चक्षुः चक्षुः चक्षुः तेजः स्थिरो भव।
मां पाहि पाहि ।
त्वरितं चक्षुरोगान् शमय शमय ।
मम जातरूपं तेजो दर्शय दर्शय।
यथाऽहं अन्धो न स्यां तथा कल्पय कल्पय। कल्याणं कुरु कुरु।
यानि मम पूर्वजन्मोपार्जितानि चक्षुः। प्रतिरोधकदुष्कृतानि सर्वाणि निर्मूलय निर्मूलय।
ॐ नमः चक्षुस्तेजोदात्रे दिव्याय भास्कराय। ॐ नमः करुणाकरायामृताय।
ॐनमः सूर्याय।
ॐ नमो भगवते सूर्यायाक्षितेजसे नमः। खेचराय नमः ।
महते नमः ।
रजसे नमः ।
तमसे नमः ।
असतो मा सद्गमय ।
तमसो मा ज्योतिर्गमय।
मृत्योर्मा अमृतं गमय।
उष्णो भगवाञ्छचिरूपः।
हंसो भगवान् शुचिरप्रतिरूपः ।
य इमां चष्मतीविद्यां ब्राह्मणो नित्यमधीते न तस्याक्षिरोगो भवति।
न तस्य कुले अन्धो भवति ।
अष्टौ ब्राह्मणान् ग्राहयित्वा विद्यासिद्धिर्भवति ॥

ॐ विश्वरूपं घृणिनं जातवेदसं ।
हिरण्मयं पुरुषं ज्योतिरूपं तपन्तम्।
विश्वस्य योनिं प्रतपन्तमुग्रं पुरः प्रजानामुदयत्येष सूर्यः ॥


ॐ नमो भगवते आदित्याय अहोवाहिन्यहोवाहिनी स्वाहा ।
ॐ वयः सुपर्णा उपसेदुरिन्द्र प्रियमेधा ऋषयो नाधमानाः ।
अपध्वान्तमूर्णूहि पूर्द्धि चक्षुर्ममुग्ध्यस्मान्निधयेव बद्धान्। पुण्डरीकाक्षाय नमः ।
पुष्करेक्षणाय नमः ।
अमलेक्षणाय नमः ।
कमलेक्षणाय नमः ।
विश्वरूपाय नमः।
महाविष्णवे नमः ।।
```

**Transliteration**

```
oṃ athātaścākṣuṣīṃ paṭhitasiddhavidyāṃ cakṣurogaharāṃ vyākhyāsyāmaḥ ।
yaccakṣūrogāḥ sarvato naśyaṃti ।
cākṣuṣī dīptirbhaviṣyatīti । tasyāścākṣuṣīvidyāyā ahirbudhnya ṛṣiḥ । gāyatrī chandaḥ ।
sūryo devatā ।
cakṣuroganivṛttaye jape viniyogaḥ।
oṃ cakṣuḥ cakṣuḥ cakṣuḥ tejaḥ sthiro bhava।
māṃ pāhi pāhi ।
tvaritaṃ cakṣurogān śamaya śamaya ।
mama jātarūpaṃ tejo darśaya darśaya।
yathā'haṃ andho na syāṃ tathā kalpaya kalpaya। kalyāṇaṃ kuru kuru।
yāni mama pūrvajanmopārjitāni cakṣuḥ। pratirodhakaduṣkṛtāni sarvāṇi nirmūlaya nirmūlaya।
oṃ namaḥ cakṣustejodātre divyāya bhāskarāya। oṃ namaḥ karuṇākarāyāmṛtāya।
oṃnamaḥ sūryāya।
oṃ namo bhagavate sūryāyākṣitejase namaḥ। khecarāya namaḥ ।
mahate namaḥ ।
rajase namaḥ ।
tamase namaḥ ।
asato mā sadgamaya ।
tamaso mā jyotirgamaya।
mṛtyormā amṛtaṃ gamaya।
uṣṇo bhagavāñchacirūpaḥ।
haṃso bhagavān śucirapratirūpaḥ ।
ya imāṃ caṣmatīvidyāṃ brāhmaṇo nityamadhīte na tasyākṣirogo bhavati।
na tasya kule andho bhavati ।
aṣṭau brāhmaṇān grāhayitvā vidyāsiddhirbhavati ॥

oṃ viśvarūpaṃ ghṛṇinaṃ jātavedasaṃ ।
hiraṇmayaṃ puruṣaṃ jyotirūpaṃ tapantam।
viśvasya yoniṃ pratapantamugraṃ puraḥ prajānāmudayatyeṣa sūryaḥ ॥


oṃ namo bhagavate ādityāya ahovāhinyahovāhinī svāhā ।
oṃ vayaḥ suparṇā upasedurindra priyamedhā ṛṣayo nādhamānāḥ ।
apadhvāntamūrṇūhi pūrddhi cakṣurmamugdhyasmānnidhayeva baddhān। puṇḍarīkākṣāya namaḥ ।
puṣkarekṣaṇāya namaḥ ।
amalekṣaṇāya namaḥ ।
kamalekṣaṇāya namaḥ ।
viśvarūpāya namaḥ।
mahāviṣṇave namaḥ ।।
```

Answer (score 0):

We all know famous 108 upanishads(mukhya upanishads) , but many are not well known (some consider them to be new upanishad). Chakshumati Vidya comes from chakshushopanishat or its another name is netropanishat.

https://archive.org/details/Aprakashita.Upanishad/page/n33/mode/2up. Here you will find this upanishad where whole mantra has been given, the author has compiled 71 minor upanishads which don't come under category of mukhya upanishad.

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/chakshu.pdf Here also mantras are present , but alongwith it procedure is mentioned too.